# Gstreamer Python Change Filesrc

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to write a program that plays a movie on my raspberry pi 2 and - when a special message comes in - goes to another track/video or pauses/unpauses the video.

The connection to the outside world lives in another thread that is not in that code, I have substituted this one with the sleep() part in the main function.

The Problem is when I change the videofile while still playing (by calling `player.setFile(filesrc)`) I get an error Message like:

```
glGetError 0x505
** (python2:3186): WARNING **: Use gst_egl_image_allocator_alloc() to allocate from this allocator
```

or

```
** (python2:3269): CRITICAL **: gst_omx_component_close_tunnel: assertion 'port1->tunneled && port2->tunneled' failed
```

and sometimes a segmentation fault.

**Question:** How can I change the playing video with gstreamer1.0 and python without reinitializing all the player stuff (that takes quite long - around 2 seconds - on the rpi2) - so how do I need to rewrite the method `setFile(filesrc)` to work

Excerpt from my Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

imports ....

videoPause = "video.mp4"


class gst_decodebin:
    def __init__(self):

        self.mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new('playallpipeline')

        self.filesrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesrc', 'filesrc')
        self.filesrc.set_property('location', videoPause)
        self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc)

        self.decode = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decodebin', 'decode')
        self.pipeline.add(self.decode)
        self.decode.connect('pad-added', self.decode_src_created)

        self.audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert', 'audioconvert')
        self.videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'videoconvert')

        self.queueaudio = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'queueaudio')
        self.queuevideo = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'queuevideo')

        self.videosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('eglglessink', 'videosink')
        self.audiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('alsasink', 'audiosink')

        #self.audiosink.set_property('device', 'hw:1,0')
        self.audiosink.set_property('device', 'hw:0,0')

        # Zur Pipeline adden
        self.pipeline.add(self.audioconvert)
        self.pipeline.add(self.videoconvert)

        self.pipeline.add(self.queueaudio)
        self.pipeline.add(self.queuevideo)

        self.pipeline.add(self.videosink)
        self.pipeline.add(self.audiosink)

        # Elemente verlinken
        self.filesrc.link(self.decode)
        self.queueaudio.link(self.audioconvert)
        self.audioconvert.link(self.audiosink)
        self.queuevideo.link(self.videoconvert)
        self.videoconvert.link(self.videosink)

        # Bus für Nachrichten aufsetzen
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()   
        self.bus.connect('message', self.message)    

    # Callback für decode.connected
    def decode_src_created(self, element, pad):
        pad.link(self.queuevideo.get_static_pad('sink'))
        pad.link(self.queueaudio.get_static_pad('sink'))

    def play(self):
        print "PLAY"
        self.playmode = "play";
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    def pause(self):
        self.playmode = "pause";
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)

    def setFile(self, filesrc):
        self.audioconvert.unlink(self.audiosink)
        self.videoconvert.unlink(self.videosink)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
        if os.path.isfile(filesrc):
            print "Setting File to %s" % filesrc
            self.filesrc.set_property('location', filesrc)
        else:
            print "Setting File to Pause"
            self.filesrc.set_property('location', videoPause)
        self.audioconvert.link(self.audiosink)
        self.videoconvert.link(self.videosink)
        self.play()

    def stop(self):
        self.playmode = "stop";
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


    def message(self, bus, message):
        mtype = message.type
        if mtype == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            self.exit()
        elif mtype == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            print 'Error: %s' % err, debug
        self.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GObject.threads_init()

    Gst.init(None)
    player = gst_decodebin()


    player.setFile("/media/source/first/other/video.mp4")
    player.play();
    time.sleep(3)
    player.setFile("/media/source/to/other/video.mp4")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `pad probe mechanism`.
https://coaxion.net/blog/2014/01/gstreamer-dynamic-pipelines/

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.